# Image resizing inside a StackLayout in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, stacklayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="StackStuff.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Image Source="image.jpg" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

I have a Xamarin.Forms project where I want an image to resize inside a StackLayout. I stripped it down to the minimal code above and if I resize the window, the image will only resize based off the window width. i.e. the image gets clipped off the bottom of the window if I change the height.

If I change the StackLayout's Orientation to Horizontal, I get the opposite - it'll resize based off a changing height, but not width.

If I completely remove the StackLayout and have only the image on the page, then the entire image will always be visible which is the behaviour I expected when it's inside the StackLayout.

Can anyone explain why this is? If I replace the Image with a BoxView, it'll happily resize and stay within the bounds of the StackLayout.

Thanks.

Comment: Check Aspect property = uniformfill

Comment: @Cfun There is no uniformfill for the Aspect property in Xamarin.Forms. the default is AspectFit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.aspect?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: sorry I couldn't understand your problem better, but just as an suggestion - did you tried setting VerticalOptions & HorizontalOptions of image & stack layout to FillAndExpand?

Comment: @Blu, thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I've tried all of the Horizontal and Vertical options. I'm pretty sure I'm not doing anything wrong and it's a limitation of a StackLayout but it'd be interesting to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you could try showing two screenshots to make your question more clear ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by wrapping the image in a grid:

```
<StackLayouenter code heret Orientation="Vertical">
    <Grid>        
        <Image Source="image.jpg" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

I have no idea why it works but I guess that's Xamarin.Forms for you.